# Java and Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, server

I got my Java server deployed on Heroku. Im creating a server socket there and I can not find the way to set the PORT for this. I kinda see in Heroku logs a PORT that it gives me, but I dont know how to use it in my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

here is how you can do it

```
    public int getPort() {

    String port = System.getenv("PORT");

    if (port == null || port.isEmpty()) {
        port = "8888";  // default
    }


    return Integer.valueOf(port);
}
```